# sql expression in ms access to understand

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created a right  join in one table . I am new to sql so I am not understanding why I get this result so I need your help please.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 
1    29   10    90
2    29   12    100
3    28   17    200
4    30   22    400
5    28   24    50

select 88, 10, date(), IIF(not IsNull(pay.col3), pay.col3, 50  ) - 10
FROM table AS pay right JOIN
     (SELECT max(col1) AS id
      FROM table
      where col2 = 88
     )  AS max2
     ON pay.col1 = max2.id
```

The result is  88, 10, 11/03/2021, 40
But it looks to me it should not return any result at all.

Comment: Assuming the grid shown above represents every row in "table", col2 contains no value 88.  In these circumstances the table instance on the right hand side of the join will return no rows.  Therefore, the join operation will return nothing.

Comment: that's correct @v0rl0n, but the max(col1) on the right side will return one result (which will = null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a null result from SELECT max(col1) as id. Max returns null when there are zero rows for it to evaluate. This is different from getting no result at all. For comparison, try removing the max (i.e. just use SELECT col1 AS id), which will return nothing.

Comment: Yes but even in this case the resoult should not be the one I wrote above

Comment: yes, it should. You got one result from your max2 derived table. It's a null value, but it's still a result. This will give you the same result, for example: SELECT 88, date(), 50 - 10
FROM table AS pay RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT TOP 1 NULL AS id from col2) AS max2
ON pay.serviceid = max2.id

Comment: Change "TOP 1" to "TOP 2" or "TOP 3" and it should be clearer

Comment: It does give the result. The overall join produces one row. In this row all the columns specified by the first SELECT are returned as specified. Have you tried any of the variations that I suggested? You will see clearly is happening if you try those other selects. If you still doubt it, I can include examples in my answer.

Comment: The first select(without join) should give the result : 88,10,12-03-2021,10| 88,10,12-03-2021,12|88,10,12-03-2021,17|88,10,12-03-2021,22|88,10,12-03-2021,24|(5 rows in total ) The second select without join should give a null value. I dont understand why the right join of above selects would give the result 88,10,12-03-2021,40  as this row is in none of the selects above

Comment: that's because it is a RIGHT JOIN, which means everything from the right (one row of null) and only the rows that match *and any scalar values* (e.g. 88, 10, date(), 50 - 10) on the left. Because there is overall one row, all your scalar values are returned as specified on that one row. In contrast, had your second select without join returned 2 rows, you would see the scalar values on both rows with the join.

Comment: If you would like me to improve the answer, I can do it with your suggestions. If you feel that it has answered your question, could you please accept it? (Click check mark (✓)). Thanks!